# .htaccess rule seemingly ignored

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, marionette, phalcon

I have a Marionette application that manages routes, but I don't want it handling them for api call requests to server.com/api/anything/at/all

My rule looks like this at the moment, but Marionette seems to be always catching it, even when it's for /api/*

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Marionette                                                                    |
# | If it's not for /api/*, then handle it                                        |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectorySlash Off
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php $1 [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php
</ifModule>
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Phalcon                                                                    |
# | If it fell through, handle with Phalcon                                    |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong here please? Thanks.

Edit: If it gives any clarity, the above .htaccess is in my /public folder. In the root folder I have:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Phalcon                                                                    |
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

That public rewrite works fine. I just thought I'd share it in case there's something about it affecting the one in public that I'm not thinking of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `Marionette` rule should be like this:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectorySlash Off
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php $1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(index\.php|api/) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: I replaced my block with yours and I still get the same response.

server.com/ -- Marionette          
server.com/api/ -- Marionette          
server.com/api/test -- Marionette

Comment: Yes, that worked - thank you. Any idea on how I ensure that it's only working for server.com/api/x/y/z? I tested with server.com/marionette/api/ and because it contained 'api' it feel through the rule to phalcon. So I'm looking to make the rule say that /api/ is at the start?

Comment: I tweaked rule further to match `/api/` only at start.